# java rmi client exceptions

Tags: java, rmi

I'm writing an rmi application. Everything works perfectly fine when i put the all classes in one directory(one single package). However, when i try to split the server part and the client part, exceptions happens to the client. Server works normally.
Here is part of the stack trace of after exception happens:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
    java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
        java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.clientpackage.ClientImpl_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
```

I used unicastRemoteobject method to pass the server an instance of an object from client for the callback. I also use rmic to generate the stub file for the object. It seems that the the program can't find that stub class on its CLASSPATH. I'm wondering how to I solve this problem?

Comment: Were you able to fix the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are using `rmic`. Unless you are using a version of Java strictly *prior to* Java 5, this is not recommended.

Java 5 and later version will generate a stub dynamically. Using `rmic` is only necessary if you have to support Java 1.4 or older clients.

In Java 5 and later, if the stubs are generated with `rmic`, and are present on the *server's* class path, the client will try to load them through the RMI class loader, *even if they are already available on the client's class path.*

Also, if you don't intend to use the RMI class loader, there's no need to set the server codebase.

Comment: +1 because you obviously have seen this problem before :)

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.StubNotFoundException: Stub class not found...
I got rid of the stub file generated by rmic. It now throws the excepions show above. Do you have an idea why is this?

Comment: 1) Are you running Java 5 or later? 2) Did you restart the RMI registry? 3) Did you clean up *all* artifacts produced by `rmic`?

Comment: I can't make any sense of your last paragraph. If the stubs *aren't* on the server's CLASSPATH, the server won't be able to export itself, unless it is elegible to use dynamic proxies, in which case the stub will never be loaded by anybody.

Comment: @EJP Did you mean second to last paragraph?

Comment: This answer is not correct. The problem is *not* that you are using `rmic`. The problem is that you are using it *without distributing the stub files to the client.* You can choose not to use it, if you satisfy the requirements stated in the Javadoc for `UnicastRemoteObject`, but this merely reduces the number of files you need to distribute. By one.

Comment: @erickson Yes I do, my mistake. I believe you are incorrect about the 'even if' part, too.